# How can I send a binary message between two clients using WebRTC?

Tags: javascript, html, sockets, udp, webrtc

I'd like to implement a function:

```
function send(ip, port, message) { ... }
function onMessage(port, callback) { ... }
```

Which could be used to send binary messages (`Uint8Array`) between browsers directly. Example:

```
// peer #1
onMessage(7171, (msg) => console.log("received:", msg));

// peer #2
setInterval(() => send("localhost", 7171, new Uint8Array([1,2,3,4])), 100);
```

The program above should repeatedly print the `[1,2,3,4]` array. I've been looking at WebRTC specs and examples for days, and I still didn't get a simple answer of how to implement those 2 functions.

How can I send a binary message between two clients using WebRTC?

Comment: you should look to [WebRTC DataChannel](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webrtc/datachannels/)

Comment: Have you looked at  RTCDataChannel.binaryType?.Details here :
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/RTCDataChannel/binaryType

Comment: Yes, this still doesn't answer the question, I believe.